# .py script autostart

Tags: autostart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start applications at startup automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-to-start-applications-at-startup-automatically)

I'm using simple tiling manager.This programm have one .py file.
How to autostart this .py file with parameters after login?
If it important, i'm using gnome 2.

Already tried to add bash script, which runs my .py to rc.local, but nothing.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-to-start-applications-at-startup-automatically

Comment: You may want to put `python path/to/myscript.py myoptions` to the startup command or `.desktop`-file as is further elaborated in the question/answer above.

Comment: Thanks. I'm already add .desktop, which runs bash script. It works.

Answer (score 1):

Create a launcher for your script then add to the startup applications